# Display stored images

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I have some variables `sessionStorage` containing sources of images, and what i should do is displaying them. In my HTML page I tried like this:

```
</div>
<h1 id="h1poggia">
    Here's your choices:
</h1>
<div>
    <script src="Script1.js">
        riep();
    </script>
</div>
```

And this is the funcion:

```
    function riep() {
    imuno = sessionStorage.getItem('imuno');
    imdue = sessionStorage.getItem('imdue');
    document.write(imuno, imdue);
}
```

But it seems the function doesn't even get retrieved! Where am I wrong?

Comment: have you tried looking in the browser's console? Does it emit an error message? Is the script file in the same directory as the html file? (Maybe the browser can't find it)

Comment: It's better to wait for the page to finish loading if you're working with the DOM. Try `window.onload=riep;` instead of `riep();`

Comment: Browser's console doesn't emit any error message, and the HTML and JS files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't works:

```
<script src="Script1.js">
    riep();
</script>
```

If you need to include an external script and then call to function maybe you need to separate that:

```
<script src="Script1.js"></script> 
<script>
    riep();
</script>
```

However you are using `document.write` that's dangerous and deprecated. Please, use this instead:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = imuno+", "+imdue;
```

And set an ID to the div:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, my problem was exaclty that! I had to separate them, thank you very much! How can i display images instead of src?

Comment: You need to ask a different question to `display images instead of src`, but try to read this before: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It is no difficult, you can open another question in stackoverflow and all will be ordered and you'll obtain better answers. Good luck!